# Common programming mistakes for Haskell developers to avoid?

Tags: haskell

In the spirit of the other common mistakes in  questions, what are the most common mistakes that Haskell programmers make?  I've been teaching myself Haskell for a little while and I am starting to feel comfortable enough with the language to start applying it in the real world.

Comment: And another should-be-community-wiki...

Comment: This style of question is usually better appreciated as a Community Wiki.

Comment: It's hard to imagine why this is "not a real question" when there are so many other "common programming mistakes" questions on SO that have survived.

Comment: To the Wiki police: go check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216577/common-programming-mistakes-for-java-developers-to-avoid.  It's not marked community wiki either.

Comment: @Robert:  It's a real question, but because there is no definitive answer, "discussion-style" questions are often viewed as more suitable for community wiki.

Comment: It's impossible to enforce your standard, as there are no system safeguards in place to do so.  It is especially difficult to enforce it consistently, as the Java question so eloquently illustrates.

Comment: @Imagist, in case you are wondering what this is all about, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128434/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow

Comment: I would also suggest creating a page on the Haskell wiki, and soliciting comments. We have a section for common idioms. You're looking for anti-idioms. http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/Category:FAQ

Comment: Hmm, maybe it's too early on a Saturday morning for me, but the Java question appears to be marked Community Wiki now (always was?).  Here's a better example:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383229/common-programming-mistakes-for-ruby-developers-to-avoid

Comment: @Imagist: as indicated by Robert Harvey's 5 comments in your own thread, some people are just on a crusade. Community wiki means "community owned", it is not a category and its not a synonym for "discussion" questions. Ignore the community wiki police.

Comment: I don't really care if it's community wiki or not, I just want my question answered.  Thanks for your support though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The most common mistake I know of is introducing a **space leak through lazy evaluation**.  There are lots of ways to achieve this mistake, but one that especially nails programmers with other functional-programming experience is to put a result in an accumulating parameter, thinking that the accumulating parameter will take constant space.  In many cases the accumulating parameter takes linear space because parameters are not evaluated.

Another common mistake is to **forget that `let` is always recursive**.  An unintentional

```
let x = ... x ...
```

can lead to *baffling* outcomes.

Most other common bad experiences manifest not as mistakes but as trouble getting programs past the type checker, or difficulty understanding the monadic I/O model.  Difficulties with list comprehensions and with `do` notations occur occasionally.

In general the difficulties faced by beginning Haskell programmers include

- Large language with many dark corners, especially in the type system
- Trouble getting programs to compile, especially when they do I/O
- Doing everything in the `IO` monad
- Great difficulty predicting the time and space behavior of lazy functional programs

Answer (score 8):

A common mistake for *beginning* Haskell programmers is to [forget the difference between constructor and type namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032948/haskell-lists-of-datatypes).  That was such a beginner's mistake that I'm about embarrassed to have my name attached to it, but I'm pretty confident that others will stumble upon that answer when they have a similar problem, so may as well keep it out there.

Answer (score 4):

The difference between `[]` and `[[]]`: the empty list and the list with 1 element, namely the empty list. This one especially pops up in base cases of recursive functions.

Answer (score -1):

Use non tail-recursive functions or not strict folds occurring to stack overflow.

Comment: This is less true in Haskell than other functional languages. A lot of the time, laziness makes the non-tail versions of functions a better choice (e.g. you can `foldr` an infinite list, while the tail-recursive `foldl` will explode every time).

Comment: I know it, but head (x:xs) = head xs + 1 won't explode on a list of 1000000 items?

Comment: I had tried `head'' (x:xs) = let x' = head'' xs in x' \`seq\` x' + 1`, without success.  Anyone have any clues?

Comment: Switched to accumulating parameter, is there not another way?

`head''' :: [Int] -> Int
head''' = f 0
  where
    f acc [] = acc
    f acc (x:xs) = f (acc + 1) xs
`

Comment: @ScootyPuff, Both versions works for me, just the accumulating version is faster.